# bash array slicing strange syntax in perl path: `${PATH:+:${PATH}}"`

Tags: bash, path, parameter-expansion

On Linux Ubuntu, when you do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install perl`, it adds the following to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file (at least, many months later, I think that is what added those lines):

```sh
PATH="/home/gabriel/perl5/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"; export PATH;
PERL5LIB="/home/gabriel/perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5LIB;
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/gabriel/perl5${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:+:${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT}}"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/home/gabriel/perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/gabriel/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
```

What does this strange syntax do in many of the lines, including in the first line? It appears to be some sort of bash array slicing:

```sh
${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

The `${PATH}` part is pretty straightforward: it reads the contents of the `PATH` variable, but the rest is pretty cryptic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not array slicing; it's a use of one of the POSIX parameter expansion operators. From the `bash` man page, in the Parameter Expansions section,

> ${`parameter`:+`word`}
>
> **Use  Alternate Value.**  If `parameter` is null or unset, nothing is
> substituted, otherwise the expansion of `word` is substituted.

It's a complex way of making sure that you only add a `:` to the value if `PATH` isn't empty to start with. A longer, clearer way of writing it would be

```
if [ -n "$PATH" ]; then
    PATH=/home/gabriel/perl5/bin:$PATH
else
    PATH=/home/gabriel/perl5/bin
fi
```

However, since it if almost inconceivable that `PATH` is empty when `.basrhc` is sourced, it would be simpler to just prepend the new path and be done with it.

```
PATH=/home/gabriel/perl5/bin:$PATH
```

If `PATH` actually ended with a `:`, it would implicitly include the current working directory in the search path, which isn't a good idea for security reasons. Also from the `bash` man page, in the section on Shell Variables under the entry for `PATH`:

> A zero-length (null) directory  name  in  the
> value of PATH indicates the current directory.  A null directory
> name may appear as two adjacent colons,  or  as  an  initial  or
> trailing  colon.

---

As an aside, it's good to understand what various installers try to add to your shell configuration. It's not always necessary, and sometimes can actively change something you already have configure.

I would much prefer if packages simply printed instructions for what needs to be added to your configuration (and why), and leave it to the user to make the appropriate modifications.

Comment: Bash is one of my primary languages. I use it even more than Python, yet it never ceases to amaze me just how much _bash is nuts._ :) It is definitely one of the less-readable languages out there.

Comment: It all stems from the fact that its basic job (run a program with arguments) requires *no* syntax aside from spaces to separate each word. That means virtually everything else requires some additional syntax to avoid confusion with executing a simple command.

Comment: (And over the years, more and more functionality has been shoehorned into a language that wasn't designed for it.)

Answer (score 1):

```
What does this strange syntax do in many of the lines, including in the first line?
```

It's the `${parameter:+word}` form of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) where `word` becomes the expanded value if `parameter` is not unset and not having the value of an empty string (a.k.a. null).